# Loading "connect_proxy.js" tasks...ERROR >> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-connect-proxy

I'm trying to run a http server using grunt. However, when I type grunt serve in the appropriate directory, I'm presented with the following errors:

```
Loading "connect_proxy.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
Loading "connect_proxy.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Comment: What does your connect_proxy.js code look like?  Can you run this as a WebServer using Node without issues?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some dependencies issues, look at this, apparently its solved if you update your "grunt-connect-proxy"

```
"devDependencies": {
"grunt-connect-proxy": "^0.2.0"
}
```

https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy/issues/97